# Blazor WebAssembly unable locate App.razor after updating to .net8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

After updating visual studio to Version 17.9.0 and updating to .net 8.0.200 my Blazor WebAssembly stopped working, in project.cs

```
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
```

I am getting.

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

even though `App.razor` is in the same namespace.

### App.razor

```xml
@using MyApp.Client;
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

### Program.cs

```cs
using Blazored.Toast;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Polly;
using MyApp.Client.Helper;
using Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry;
using MyApp.Shared.Models;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyApp.Client
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
            builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
            builder.Services.AddBlazoredToast();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<EventService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationDataMemoryStorage>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<BlazorSchoolAuthenticationStateProvider>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<ClipboardService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<BlazorSchoolAuthenticationStateProvider>());
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("HttpClient",
            httpClient =>
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
            })
            .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(policyBuilder => policyBuilder.WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5)));

            builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IHttpService, HttpService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<ILocalStorageService, LocalStorageService>();
            builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
            builder.Services.AddBlazorDialog();
            builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
            builder.Services.AddLocalization();
            var host = builder.Build();
            CultureInfo culture;
            var js = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
            var result = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("blazorCulture.get");

            if (result != null)
            {
                culture = new CultureInfo(result);
            }
            else
            {
                culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                await js.InvokeVoidAsync("blazorCulture.set", "en-US");
            }

            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add app.razor.cs then it complies but the app is not loaded, a blank page is shown after the loading screen and no error is given.

Comment: did you remove the obj and bin directories? Usually it's needed to do that manually after a major version upgrade. Also: did you also update all the related projects? Also have a look at: Micosoft's [Migrate from ASP.NET Core in .NET 7 to .NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80).

Answer (score 0):

If you read [Convert a hosted Blazor WebAssembly app into a Blazor Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80#update-a-blazor-webassembly-app) it shows the ways to update from net 7 to net 8. You likely didn't follow all these.

E.g. at point 5 it says:

> Rename `App.razor` in the `.Client` project to `Routes.razor`.